# How to generate random number between 0 and 1 using a sha256 hash

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash, sha256

I have a randomly generated sha256 hash and would like to generate a number between 0 and 1 based on this hash. How do I go about doing this?

```js
var hash = crypto.createHmac("sha256", config.server_seed).update(this.roundID).digest("hex");

var randomNumber = parseInt(hash, 16) // am I along the right tracks here?
```

Comment: Well, what does this code accomplish for you? Have you tested it?

Comment: If this has anything to do with security, you're going to have a bad time. Numbers in JavaScript have less precision than what you need to represent a sha256 hash. While you can map a hash to a number, it won't be as secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to divide `randomNumber` by the SHA256 hash space size, which is `Math.pow(2, 256)`:

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac("sha256", config.server_seed).update(this.roundID).digest("hex");

var randomNumber = parseInt(hash, 16) / Math.pow(2, 256);
```

Although I'm not sure why you would want to do this...

Comment: Ayy thank you man, worked perfectly.

It's not for any reason in particular. It's just a random through that occurred - Whether I could convert a hash into a percentage for probability related stuff.